# Htaccess URL redirect by matching url string and parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I need to match the URL format and depends on URL matches need to redirect the incoming requests to different pages.

For example

**http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/** wrong-url **-1/** ?var1=val1
**http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/** another-wrong-url **-1/** ?var1=val1
**http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/** third-wrong-url **-1/**?var1=val1
**http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/** fourth-wrong-url **-1/**?var1=val1

See the High lighted URL Matches. It always having **-1 as the url string.** . That needs to be redirected one static page.

And some other URL's always have **var1** as URL Query String parameter. So if URL have **var1**  as Query string then those URL's needs to be redirected to another Static page.

So i tried this but didn't worked. Please help me in this redirecting script

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(path1/path2/[^-1]*)$ http://www.domain.com/target-page [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rule for URL that ends with `-1/`:

```
RewriteRule ^path1/path2/([^/]+)-1/$ http://www.domain.com/target-page [L,R=301]
```

2. Rule for having `var1=` parameter in query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)var1=([^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/another-target-page [L,R=301]
```

**NOTE:**
With these rules existing query string will be passed to a new URL as well (e.g. `/path1/path2/wrong-url-1/?say=meow` will become `http://www.domain.com/target-page?say=meow`). To drop it, add `?` at the end of target URL (e.g. `http://www.domain.com/another-target-page? [L,R=301]`

Comment: great. Thanks a lot. I Have added this . **RewriteRule ^wine/appellation/(.*)-1$ http://www.domain.com/gifts/?  [L,R=301]** and it works perfectly. But for Query string still its not working. I dont know what mistake am doing. Let me try t out more.

Comment: It's my fault (typo): should be `%` character and not `$`: change `${QUERY_STRING}` to `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Yes I was added % only and it was not working when i test it last day. Today certainly its worked. Thanks a lot